# i can't get datetimepicker in my springmvc project

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I would like to insert a datetimepicker or just a timepicker using bootstrap on a form in my web project. Only the datepicker is working.
here is my code.

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datepicker').datepicker();
            });
</script>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dateDebutGlacage">DateDebutGlacage</label> 
    <f:input class="form-control" path="dateDebutGlacage" id="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="DateDebutGlacage"></f:input>
```

Comment: [Reference this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using jQueryUI's date picker which is only for dates and not for time.

You can look at this jQuery plugin that is built for that:

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/